# SIM card balance for in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-billing, gsm

I just want to know if there is a possibility to a user to make in-app purchases directly in his SIM card account. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simcard, If you mean the card provided by the service provider then you have to contact the clients/users service provider directly. Then you have to go through their rules to accept the payment. Service providers requires you to be a verified 3rd party so contact them first.